# Best adhesive to fix a model for long term display?

Tags: glue

What is the best adhesive to make a model into a permanent display like into a Christmas decoration or an ornament? I want for this model to withstand being packed and unpacked year after year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest standard Elmer's glue (also referred to as school glue). It won't harm your LEGO so you can later remove the glue if you need to, but it is strong enough to keep a set together under normal use.

Comment: Have you used it with success?

Comment: Yes, it is fine for most models. LEGO has good clutch-power already, so it only needs a little help from glue. If the model is very fragile though, and there is not much holding it together (for example something like a snowflake model), you may need to use superglue. However superglue will damage LEGO and you won't be able to ever separate the pieces again. It is best to just make the model stronger instead of gluing it. Glue is a real no-no in the eyes of most LEGO fans. LEGO ornaments I have seen are pretty compact and strong on their own. Those are the best kind. :)